# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: relation "instructions" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

HI,

I got this error when i am testing my rails application. I dont have the table named 'instructions'. But it shows a error like "ERROR:  relation "instructions" does not exist". Totally, I got same error for 64 tests as 64 errors.

I am using rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2, Netbeans 6.8.

PS: I didnt creat Instruction manual for rails application.

**Error:
test_should_get_index(HomeControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "instructions" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "instructions"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "instructions"**

Kindly help me in this regard

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want to run  `rake db:test:prepare` , the table instructions isn't present in your test database.

Comment: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "gold_strain_assignments_pkey" for table "gold_strain_assignments"
Started
EEEEEEEEE
Finished in 0.147813 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_the_truth(InstructionTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "taxonomic_links" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "taxonomic_links"

Comment: It shows the above error, before that my database had many tables the "rake db:test:prepare" process deleted some of tables in test database. I am so weird.

Comment: Do you have a separate database for test or not ? . I mean .. Test database are supposed to be different, and some how you have messed your table structure, usually tables don't get deleted unless you don't want them to. Are you using migrations for everything, something might be wrong in them. Check

Comment: yaa... yaa, I have seperate database. I am saying about test database only. Some of tables in test database got deleted. Bcz, some tables are not trace to test database when i am doing db:test:prepare or db:test:load. I am used migrations for everything.

Comment: It doesnt show problem for other tables through schema. It shows problem for "instructions" which created default by rails 3. "Instructions is not a table which come under schema of psql database"- So, i am thinking that this maynot be a migration issues or preparatory issue to psql. But, execution considers "instructions" as a table in psql. I understood in this aspect and i cant trace the error between the misunderstand of "instructions" as table in psql database.

Answer (score 9):

Check your fixtures. I hit an error like this when using Rails scaffolding to generate a subclassed resource.

The generator had created files in my test/fixtures/ directory that didn't correspond to any actual tables in my database (since the model was using STI under another table).

When running tests, Rails attempted to instantiate all my fixtures, and an error similar to yours was generated when it could not find a table matching the name of the fixture.

Deleting the unneeded fixture file cleared my error and got tests running.

Hope that helps you, or others who arrive here searching that error, as I did. :]

Comment: I had the same exact problem and this fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me to check fixtures. That totally was it for me. I never would have guessed that!